# Need help to move files from one directory to another with shell script

Tags: sh

There will be a directory, which will contain various file types(xlsx, gpg, txt).

If .gpg then only invoke the decrypt.sh or else move the file to output folder.

Anyone who could help me the same?

Comment: Do you have any exampled of code that you have tried that is not working the way you would like it to? Please post any examples and the resulting aberrant behavior

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `bash` (likely), you can iterate over the files in a directory with the `for` command, such as in the following transcript:

```
pax> ls -al
total 4
drwxr-xr-x    5 pax ubergeeks        0 Jun  7 16:01 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 pax ubergeeks     8192 Jun  7 16:01 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 pax ubergeeks        0 Jun  7 16:01 file 1.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 pax ubergeeks        0 Jun  7 16:01 file 2.gpg
-rw-r--r--    1 pax ubergeeks        0 Jun  7 16:01 file 3.xlsx

pax> for fspec in *.txt *.gpg *.xlsx ; do
...>    echo "==> '$fspec'"
...> done
==> 'file 1.txt'
==> 'file 2.gpg'
==> 'file 3.xlsx'
```

You can test if a string variable ends in a specific string by using the regular expression operator:

```
if [[ "${fspec}" =~ \.gpg$ ]] ; then
    echo it ends with .gpg
fi
```

And, of course, you can run a script or move a file with commands like:

```
/path/to/decrypt.sh "${fspec}
mv "${fspec}" /path/to/output
```

---

So, combining all that, a good starting point would be (making sure you specify real paths rather than my `/path/to/` placeholders):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd /path/to/files
for fspec in *.txt *.gpg *.xlsx ; do
    if [[ "${fspec}" =~ \.gpg$ ]] ; then
        echo "Decrypting '${fspec}'"
        /path/to/decrypt.sh "${fspec}"
    else
        echo "Moving '${fspec}'"
        mv "${fspec}" /path/to/output
    fi
done
```